# How to I keep kable from formatting text that follows the table?

Tags: r-markdown

I'm relatively new to knitr.  I'm trying to create a document that includes a small table.  For example, consider this rmd document:

````
---
title: "Kable Test"
author: "Dave"
date: "January 8, 2016"
output: html_document
---

This R Markdown document is for testing kable output when kable is given a data.frame with only one row. 

```{r}
library(knitr)
df = data.frame(x=1,y=100,z=1000)

kable(df)
```
This text is after the table.
````

When I knit this document the text "This text is after the table." gets formatted as if it is in the table.

I have found if I include an empty chunk between the kable(df) and the plain text that the plain text is formatted properly.

````
```{r}
kable(df)
```
```{r}
```
Same table followed by an empty chunk.
````

In this case, "Same table ..." is formatted correctly.

Are there parameters to kable that I should be using so that I can avoid inserting the empty chunk?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra line break (empty line) between the end of the chunk and your new paragraph:

````
---
title: "Kable Test"
author: "Dave"
date: "January 8, 2016"
output: html_document
---

This R Markdown document is for testing kable output when kable is given a data.frame with only one row. 

```{r}
library(knitr)
df = data.frame(x=1,y=100,z=1000)

kable(df)
```

This text is after the table.
````

Or use `pander::pander`, which does that automatically (by always adding an extra line-break after the table to avoid this confusion) with some further sugar:

````
---
title: "Kable Test"
author: "Dave"
date: "January 8, 2016"
output: html_document
---

This R Markdown document is for testing kable output when kable is given a data.frame with only one row. 

```{r}
library(knitr)
df = data.frame(x=1,y=100,z=1000)

pander::pander(df)
```
This text is after the table.
````

Comment: Thank you.  I swear I tried the extra blank line and it didn't work.  However, when I just tried it again it worked great.